# An Inequality in von Neumann algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

In Section $9.9$ of the book 'Lectures on von Neumann algebras' by Strătilă and Zsidó, I am not getting how they get the following inequality:

Given a positive self-adjoint linear operator $A$ in the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, we have $a=(1+A)^{-1}\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}) \text{ and } 0\leq a \leq 1$. For any natural number $n$, let ${\chi}_n$ be the characteristic function of the set $((n+1)^{-1},+\infty)$. Let us define $e_n={\chi}_n(a)$.

**Problem:** Then there exists a unique $a_n\in\mathcal{R}(\{a\})$ ($\mathcal{R}(\{a\})$ stands for the von Neumann algebra generated by the element $a$) such that $e_n\leq a_n\leq (n+1)e_n$ and $e_n=aa_n$.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If $E$ is he spectral measure of $a$, then the von Neumann algebra generated by $a$ is $\ast$-isomorphic to $L^\infty(\sigma(a),E)$.  In other words, you can assume that $a$ is a measurable function with values in $[0,1]$, and everything should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(t)=\tfrac1t\,1_{\bigl(\tfrac1{n+1},\infty\bigr)}(t)$. Define
$$
a_n=f(a).
$$
Then, since $tf(t)=\chi_n$,
$$
e_n=aa_n. 
$$

As
$$
\,1_{\big(\tfrac1{n+1},1\big]}(t)\leq \tfrac1t\,1_{\big(\tfrac1{n+1},1\big]}(t)\leq (n+1)\,1_{\big(\tfrac1{n+1},1\big]}(t),
$$
we get
$$
e_n\leq a_n\leq (n+1)\,e_n. 
$$
Uniqueness: if $aa_n=ab_n$, then $a(a_n-b_n)=0$. Then $f(a)\,(a_n-b_n)=0$ for all continuous $f$; as $\{f(a):\ f\ \text{ continuous } \}$ is dense in $\mathcal R(a)$, we get that $a_n-b_n=0$.